# How to resize non-sequential partitions containing os?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I've had a Windows 8.1 installation on my 128GB SSD which is all I have on my old laptop. Suddenly I decided to say my goodbyes to windows stuff. So I went for Ubuntu, but decided on dual boot for some time in case I need some specific software which only can be installed on windows.

At first I dedicated 32GB to Ubuntu `/` but now I feel low on space, so I completely deleted Windows and its boot partition.

Here is what I have now:

```
Free Space        Partition 3            Partition 4
----------       -------------        ------------------
   88GB          1GB FAT (EFI)        31GB Ext4 (Ubuntu)
```

What I need to do is to extend my `Ubuntu Partition` to 80GB but as you can see I guess I can't because the `Free Space` is separated from `Ubuntu Partition` by `EFI Partition`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Using a live USB stick you need to move partion3 to the beginning of your free space. That can be done with `gparted`- which you could install with `sudo apt install gparted`if not already installed.
(gparted has a move command for partitions)
Now you can enlarge your Ubuntu partion.

Make sure to select the correct device (e.g. /dev/sda1) when you open gparted

Comment: Please read the question carefully, I wanted to extend ```Ubuntu Partition``` which was at the end of the disk and there was ```EFI Partition``` between the ```Free Space``` and ```Ubuntu Partition``` so it wasn't possible without unmounting ```Ubuntu Partition``` while it was being used.

Comment: Correct, you should do this with a live USB stick. I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which was pretty easy.

- I installed **Gparted** with the command `sudo apt-get install gparted`.
- Created a 1GB FAT32 partition at the beginning of the `Free Space`.
- Flagged it as `Boot` and `esp`.
- Copied `Partition 3 (EFI)` and pasted it in my new Partition.
- Ran the command `sudo update-grub`. (I don't know if it is necessary)
- Removed the previous `EFI Partition (Partition 3)`.
- Booted to an `Ubuntu Live USB`. (Gparted is installed by default)
- Moved and resized `Ubuntu Partition`.

Voila, everything still works fine. No boot/grub problem.